# Spring Hibernate Validator custom MessageSource

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator, spring-java-config

This is my first question here, so please be gentle with me :)

I'm using Spring Boot, HIbernate Validator and no XML-config

I'd like to have my Hibernate Validator to read the error messages out of my messages_xx_XX.properties files. To accomplish this I used Java config in the following way, but it doesn't work:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator();
    }

    @Bean(name = "validator")
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages/messages");
        reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setCacheSeconds(-1);
        return reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
    }
}
```

My normal Spring messages are working fine this way, but the output for my ValidatorMessages are in the form of {errorMessage}.

I've tried many solutions on the net, but nothing worked for me.
I hope you guys can help me out.

**edit:**
The idea to have all messages in one file comes from this post: http://www.silverbaytech.com/2013/04/16/custom-messages-in-spring-validation/
I did everything just like he did, but still no luck.

Comment: Can you post some key/values from your messages_xx_XX.properties as well as some Bean Validation constraints and their message configuration?

Comment: Hello Hardy,
I'm using two languages, hence I have one "message.properties" file, one "messages_en_US.properties" file and one "messages_de_DE.properties" file. In my message.properties there is for example:
`firstNameSizeError = First name cannot be empty and can only have up to {max} characters.`
The en_US file is the same as the messages.properties and in the de_DE obviously there are the german translations (of course, I didn't translate the keys ^^)
What do you mean by bean validation constraints? I don't have xml config, since I'm using @EnableAutoConfiguration .

Comment: @Hardy. Oh, now I think I know what you mean by validation constraints:
`@NotNull`
`@Size(min = 1, max = 64, message = "{firstNameSizeError}")`
`private String firstName;`
this would be the corresponding constraint for the message I posted above.